# Playing sounds on ubuntu 16.04 stops and continue suddenly

Tags: 16.04, sound

I've been using ubuntu 16.04 for a long time now, but there is a bug within the sound, whenever i play any song either on the browser or on any sound app, the sound stops working for about 2 seconds suddenly and then continue, this may happen more that once if the song length is long enough